# angular || condition and no overlap error

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having below code in the angular 6 application.

```
if (this.values.status!='Refused' || this.values.status!= 'CancelationPending'){
    foundRefused =  false;
   }
```

it shows error in editor says

```
This condition will always return 'true' since the types '"Refused"' and '"cancelationpending"' have no overlap.
```

I tried to do `toLowerCase()` in both cases but no result, I tried with one condition as it is and another with `.toLowerCase()`, it works but it goes inside loop even status is refused or cancellation pending.

Any guesses?

Comment: did you try with `!==` ?

Comment: yes, no luck same overlapping error

Comment: When `status = 'Refused'` it is not `'CancellationPending'`, so the OR passes. When `status = 'CancellationPending'`, it is not `'Refused'`, so the OR passes. With *any* other value, the `status` isn't `'Refused'`, so the OR passes. You need to use AND.

Comment: Perhaps what you need is `this.values.status !== 'Refused' && this.values.status !== 'CancelationPending'` or `this.values.status === 'Refused' || this.values.status === 'CancelationPending'`

Comment: both status can not be at one time, either one of them has to be match.. if i will put AND it will not ever go inside the loop, as I never will have same condition matching at a time.

Comment: @user12925068 but you use NOT EQUALS here. If status *isn't* `'Refused'` AND status *isn't* `'CancelationPending'` is valid logic. When it's either one, it will not pass but if it's neither, it will. Write down the truth table and check it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out

Consider `this.values.status` is 'Refused' then second condition is true

Also if `this.values.status` is 'CancelationPending' then first condition is true

if `this.value.status` is neither 'Refused' or 'CancelationPending' then both condition is true

That is why it is giving error

Consider changing condition

Like

```
if (this.values.status === 'Refused' || this.values.status === 'CancelationPending'){
   foundRefused = true;
} else {
    foundRefused = false;
}
```

Comment: Or keep the code as it is, don't flip the branches and fix the logic to `!(this.values.status === 'Refused' || this.values.status === 'CancelationPending')` for "it's not this or that". Which is also convertible using [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) `not (A or B) = not A and not B` into `this.values.status !== 'Refused' && this.values.status !== 'CancelationPending'` for "it's not this and it's not that"